# Are IE7 and 8 modes in IE9 the real thing?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

I just want to know if IE7 and IE8 modes in the F12 toolbar menus are actually using IE7 and IE8 to render pages and if there are any differences between them and their standalone counterparts?

Comment: Funny enough our site actually broke in IE8 mode on IE9, but IE8 actually handled it fine, and IE9 handled it fine in IE9 native mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are differences. From my understanding, you really can't rely on them for JavaScript because IE9 will still use its IE9 JS engine, rather than the true ones from IE7 and IE8. And I'm sure even the rendering engines aren't 100% accurate.

In all my searching for the holy grail of IE testing, there only one thing that you can truly depend on: testing actually on a Windows OS running that browser. Microsoft offers a program called Virtual PC and [provides downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575) for virtual discs that contain different versions of Windows & IE.

If you really want accuracy, this is the only way to go.

Comment: +1 we had a case where IE8 had a weird css+js combination that didn't show up with IE9 in IE8 modes.

Comment: yeah... it's too bad there isn't an easier way to do this. luckily, I work for a small enough company that i was able to single-handedly decide to drop support for IE7 altogether. IE8 isn't fun, but god help you if you're dealing with anything earlier than that...

Comment: I second the notion of using the free virtual PC from Microsoft with their IE7 and IE8 downloads.  It's a bit of a pain to do the large downloads and you have to redownload every 6 months or so, but once you get them set up, you have a perfect environment for IE6, IE7 or IE8 and they are the real thing.  You just fire them up when needed and nothing else you do on your PC disturbs them because they are standalone environments.